# How do you create a constant of a type with private fields from an external crate?

Tags: rust, constructor, constants, private

I am creating a library crate and I would like to define a `const` of a type imported from an external crate:

```rust
use external_crate::ExternalStruct;

// Error: field `field` of struct `ExternalStruct` is private
const THE_VALUE: ExternalStruct = ExternalStruct{field: 43};
```

The problem is `ExternalStruct` has private fields so I can't construct it directly like this. It also doesn't have any `const fn` constructors. Is it possible for my crate to define a `const` of type `ExternalStruct`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Would you settle for a (lazy?) static?

Comment: Or on the other hand file a PR that makes constructor `const` if it is possible.

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes I'd settle for a `static`. Can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Instead you can do one of these things:

- Modify the library to add a `const fn` constructor. Many developers aren't necessarily thinking about const usage, so a `const fn` construction might be a welcome patch to add overlooked functionality.
- If you can use a `static` instead of a `const` item, then [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) will allow you to construct the value at run time, but only once.